# New Message Notification in badges on sidebar

Tags: laravel

How can I show the number of new messages Notification in badges for example next to the messages in admin panel side bar and if admin click on messages the badge clear?
Should I broadcast?
Please help me with the algorithm.

Comment: do you mean that you have 5 new notifications that show as badges, then after you click one of the messages, the badge will be lost?

Comment: Then please tell us what you've done so far.

Comment: @JamesRiady exactly

Comment: @Wreigh I want understand best algorithm first

Comment: I can not give you the code.. but I only can give you the clue if you want

Comment: @JamesRiady I don't want code, i just want the clue, tnx for your quick respond

Comment: I have posted my answer, you can check it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example: you have 5 new message notifications right now and displaying as a badge.

make sure that your message's migration has a status's field with type boolean. This field is using to prevent displaying old messages. After you create the migration and you have the messages, displaying all the messages with the status 0(new messages). Then create a route that used to access the message like :

```
Route::get('messages', 'MessageController@showMessages');
```

After that, create a controller and when you click one of the message with status 0(new messages). Retrieve all messages with status 0(new messages) and change their status into 1(old messages) by looping them and save them.

Note: when you display your badge, make sure to check the length of messages with status 0(new messages), if the length > 0 then show the badge

Comment: I think that it's only request once.. you only loop them in your controller with five times query. you can try it first :)